# paperclip validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to validate the presence of a file with paperclip.  When I attempt to submit the form it rolls back, but for some reason it goes looking for a create.erb template which does not exist.  I don't get any sort of error message either

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_attached_file :photo,
:styles => {
:thumb => "100x100#",
:small => "750x750>" } 
validates_attachment_presence :photo


class ImagesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :require_user, :only => [:new, :create]


def new
 @image = Image.new
end



 def create

 @image = Image.new(params[:image])
 @image.user = current_user
  if @image.save
    flash[:notice] = 'image uploaded'
    redirect_to :controller => "images", :action => "index" 
 end
end

def show
@image = Image.find(params[:id])
end
```

using the gem, version 2.3.3

Comment: Could you paste your ImagesController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `create` you are not handling the case where @image.save returns false.

```
def create

  @image = Image.new(params[:image])
  @image.user = current_user
  if @image.save
    flash[:notice] = 'image uploaded'
    redirect_to :controller => "images", :action => "index" 
  else
    render :new # <== You forgot this.
  end
end
```

Without that piece it's actually trying to render `create` again, and fails.

Comment: By the way, it's better to scope image to user when you build it, instead of assigning user later. Like this: `@image = current_user.images.build(params[:image])`  (If user has_many images in your case.)

Comment: So how can i customize the error message?  In the controller I can put flash[:notice] = "upload failed".  But I would like to be more specific like   validates_attachment_presence :photo, :message => "include a file!".  This doesn't work for me though.

Comment: the `:message` thing should work. (double checked in source: http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip.rb#L325) Maybe a typo or something?